# npm publish gives "unscoped packages cannot be private"

Tags: npm

I want to publish a normal, public package to npm. When I do `npm publish` I get:

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 400
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! unscoped packages cannot be private : my-package
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[Per the NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages#publishing-scoped-public-packages), you now have to do:

```
npm publish --access public
```

This tells the npm registry that you want your package to be downloadable by everyone.

Instead of using `--access`, you can also add the setting to your `package.json`, as seen in @smnbbrv's answer below. But if I'm right an this is just a bug, you may want to just use `--access` as a temporary workaround.

Comment: yes! thank you npm team. finally, no more cold sweats that i'll accidentally end up in the wrong terminal...

Comment: thank you npm team for the clear message that requires a separate SO question / answer. Unbelievable, this is a so much breaking change, and the error message is saying random text...

Comment: @smnbbrv — ahahah, you're sure right... as though they couldn't see it coming, that such a major breaking change warrants a friendly reminder in the error message.. what's with these npm developers anyways? hahah, cheers

Comment: What a random error message, and even randomer resolution.

Comment: awesome @mb21  ;)

Comment: NPM fixed their docs, I updated the question to link to the current docs, if anyone was wondering what the comments are complaining about.

Answer (score 11):

With all the credits to @mb21 and his solution there is a small addition to his answer.

The proposed

```
npm publish --access public
```

works perfectly. However it is not always possible to make it work within the CI environment, e.g. when you use [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/npm). The proper solution there would be using the very same `access` parameter but inside your `package.json`s `publishConfig` (btw this also makes it easier to publish manually in the future):

```
{
  "name": "...",
  ...
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  }
}
```

And now you can use it within CI tools or simply

```
npm publish
```

It costed me some time to figure this out, so I hope it saves some time for the future readers.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me solve `npm err! can't restrict access to unscoped packages.`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be private, then you'll have to add a scope to your package.

Instead of `my-package` then you'll use `@my-private-libraries/my-package`